# Prevent change of document.location, when injecting the document.location JavaScript command

Tags: xss, javascript, injection

I found a reflected XSS in an application during a test, where I define the string passed to:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
document.location='/this-is-my-input'
</script>
```

Some input sanitisation occurs, for instance my string is only recorded after the first `/`. So I've managed to *escape* the document.location command by URL encoding `/'//\nalert(1)`, which runs the `alert(1)`, but immediately redirects me to the root `/` of the webapp.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the change of the document location?

*edit:* With the above mentioned user input, the code looks as follows:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
document.location='/'//
alert(1)//'
</script>
```

Comment: could you try '//\nalert(1);window.history.back()       ?
if that doesn't work, it might be a 500 error with a redirect to root as default behaviour

Comment: That would redirect me twice, wouldn't it? Once to `/` then back. I tried it and it didn't work and the console wasn't informative either, but thank you.

Comment: I misspoke, the console is for JS errors. If the server doesn't hide it, a 500 range code could be visible in the 'network' tab of your browser debugger.
If it is in fact a server side error, there's little you can do except work around it

Comment: What happens if you set the document location to your current page, but with a # at the end? Some browsers ignore redirections which are to the current page, in some cases.

Comment: That's a really good idea, but unfortunately the site *reloads* anyways, I'll try another browser though!

Comment: what about /+window.location.href+'//\nalert(1)     ?

Comment: Interesting! This keeps the javascript popup open until I forward the request for `GET /+window.location.href+` with Burp, which then 404's

Comment: with `/'+window.location.href//\nalert(1)//` the use of window.location.href works, but the resetting of the document location occurs anyways and it 404's, because it will request `example.site/http://example.site/current/path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hashfragments.

`/'.replace(/^.*$/, document.location+"#")` leads to `document.location='/'.replace(/^.*$/, document.location+"#")` which basically takes the current URL, and put a hash fragment after it. It won't reload the page since hashfragments doesn't do so on broswers.

Put whatever you want afterward like a `;alert(1)`.

Since the original code contains a `'` (ie `document.location='/'`), then don't forget to discard it, using a comment (`//` or `/*`), or by leaving your last String value unclosed (ie write `var x='My String` and let the original `'` close the string). Otherwise, it may raise a parse error and Javascript won't be executed at all.

Comment: beautiful! works like a charm! You were missing the `//` in the end, to invalidate the original closing tag `'` of the document.location.

Comment: @SaAtomic You can actually put anything else like `/*`, a simple `'`, or just not-closing your last `Stirng` value; that's why I didn't specified some ;)